# Using App Model V2 to get access to calendar

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

We have a webapplication on ASP.NET in Azure and we want to get access to the current user to his calendar to show the events for today and the number of unread emails. We have application that used graph.microsoft.com with default "Work or School Account"authentication that is created with Visual Studio, but this does not work with App Model V2.

How can build an applicaiton that is able to authenticate using App Model V2 and get access to graph.microsoft.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

A good samples is given in
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/

The step that you need to take for a App Model V2 application are:

1. Register your application using the application registration portal on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. Remember the clientID and clientsecret that is registered for you.
2. Create an asp.net in VS2015 without authentication (anonymous)
3. Add the Nuget Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
4. Add using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory to the controller
5. You need to add scope to your code as private member

private static string[] scopes = {
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.readwrite" };

5. Add add the following settings to web.config

   ```
   <add key="ida:ClientID" value="..." />
   <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="..." />
   ```
6. You have to create 2 extra methods. One for the signin and one for the authorize:

Signin:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> SignIn()
    {
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0";
        string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"];
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        // The url in our app that Azure should redirect to after successful signin
        Uri redirectUri = new Uri(Url.Action("Authorize", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme));

        // Generate the parameterized URL for Azure signin
        Uri authUri = await authContext.GetAuthorizationRequestUrlAsync(scopes, additionalScopes, clientId,
            redirectUri, UserIdentifier.AnyUser, null);

        // Redirect the browser to the Azure signin page
        return Redirect(authUri.ToString());
    }
```

Authorize:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Authorize()
    {
        // Get the 'code' parameter from the Azure redirect
        string authCode = Request.Params["code"];

        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0";
        string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"];
        string clientSecret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        // The same url we specified in the auth code request
        Uri redirectUri = new Uri(Url.Action("Authorize", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme));

        // Use client ID and secret to establish app identity
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        try
        {
            // Get the token

            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                authCode, redirectUri, credential, scopes);

            // Save the token in the session
            Session["access_token"] = authResult.Token;
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Tasks", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme));
        }
        catch (AdalException ex)
        {
            return Content(string.Format("ERROR retrieving token: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }
```

The accestoken is in a session state.

Now you can call graph.microsoft.com with the correct accesstoken and get the data:

```
        private async Task<List<DisplayEvent>> GetEvents()
    {
        List<DisplayEvent> tasks = new List<DisplayEvent>();

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var accessToken = (string)Session["access_token"];

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/me/events");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            EventModels eventList = serializer.Deserialize<EventModels>(s);

            foreach (EventModel v in eventList.value)
            {
                //Fill tasks will events
            }
        }
        return tasks;
    }
```